# Excel VBA Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with this bit of VBA code. For some reason I keep getting: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error" message. My only thought on why this may be is that I have the macro associated with a command button that is tied to a specific sheet - if this is the error, how can I resolve it? Otherwise, what might be the error here?

The line causing the error is the one beginning with MsgBox.

```
Sub Process()
    Sheets("Intermediate").Cells(2, 1).Select
    Dim contains As Range, lastRow As Long
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        MsgBox Sheets("Document Library").Columns(1).Find(ActiveCell.Value)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to mention it. It's the line beginning with MsgBox.

Comment: See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) on how to use `.Find`

Comment: Also please avoid the use of [.Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) Also you may want to find the last cell in Col A using [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) and then use a FOR LOOP?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using Sid's link as a reference, it's worth noting that the various setting for `Find()` are *persistent* - that is, if you used Find in a particular way (either via the UI or using VBA) then the next time you call `Find` those same settings will be used unless you specify otherwise.

So, it's always good practice to *specify all the settings you care about* (such as `lookAt`, `lookIn`) every time you use `Find` or you may not get the results you expect.

Also, you need to handle the event where you don't find the value being searched for - in this case Find returns `Nothing`:

```
Sub Process()
    Dim f as Range, c As Range, rngSearch as Range

    Set rngSearch = Sheets("Document Library").Columns(1)
    Set c = Sheets("Intermediate").Cells(2, 1)

    Do While Len(c.Value)>0
        'specify exactly how you want Find() to operate....
        Set f = rngSearch.Find(What:=c.Value, lookin:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            debug.print c.value & " found at " & f.address()
        Else
            debug.print c.value & " not found!" 
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The Range.Find method returns a Range Object.  The MsgBox function requires a string expression to output.  So try this:

```
MsgBox Sheets("Document Library").Columns(1).Find(ActiveCell.Value).Value
```

Note that depending on the type of the value in the cell, you may need to do a conversion to String also.

Comment: +1.  For OP, do note that this line will continue to error *if* the result of `.Find` is `Nothing` i.e., the value is not found. Additional logic is required to test for that and avoid the error :)

Comment: hm, still doesn't work for some reason, but thank you. I'm thinking that my issue has to do with having multiple worksheets going, as the sheet that I'm finding in isn't the active sheet. Could that be the case?

Comment: @DavidZemens, thanks, good point.

Comment: @stamblerre, shouldn't matter since you specify the exact sheets that you are using.

Comment: are you getting an error still? If so, what error? @stamblerre

Comment: @stamblerre, you should troubleshoot, by putting a breakpoint on that line, then using the Immediate window to check values using the Debug.Print command.

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to do that and I can't get it to show me anything meaningful. I've changed the MsgBox line to just this `contains = Sheets("Document Library").Columns(1).Find(ActiveCell.Value)` and now the error is "object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: Well, did you change the 'DIM' statement for 'contains' so it isn't a range? (Variant will be fine for testing).

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand (I am really new to VBA). I thought you said that Range.Find returns a Range object?

Comment: Default Range property is Value, so there's no need to explicitly add `.Value` (which is not to say that's not good practice)

Comment: @stamblerre, yeh, too early for me.  You need to use the 'Set' command to assign that value to 'contains' then.